# Not all of my lines are drawing in sfml vertexArray

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

So I have been working on a project with a friend but I've hit a dead end with the following code.
    // The initial angle (for the first vertex)
    double angle = PI / 2;
    //double angle=0;
    int scale = 220;
    int centerX = 300;
    int centerY = 250;

```
// Calculate the location of each vertex
for(int iii = 0; iii < vertices.getVertexCount(); iii++) {
    // Adds the vertices to the diagram
    vertices[iii].position = sf::Vector2f(centerX + cos(angle) * scale, centerY -    sin(angle) * scale);
    vertices[iii].color = sf::Color::White;

    // Calculates the angle that the next point will be at
    angle += q*(TAU / p);
}

// Draws the lines on the diagram
sf::VertexArray lines = sf::VertexArray(sf::Lines, vertices.getVertexCount());
for(int iii = 0; iii < lines.getVertexCount()-1; iii+=2) {
    lines[iii] = vertices[iii];
    lines[iii+1] = vertices[iii+1];
    lines[iii].color = sf::Color(255,(iii)*50,255,255);//sf::Color::White;
    lines[iii+1].color = sf::Color(255,(iii+1)*50,255,255);//sf::Color::White;
}
return lines;
```

The compiler doesn't give any errors but when I run the code exactly half of the lines show up, but only if p is an even number (p is the number of vertices in the polygon.) For example when I try to draw a square p=4 2 lines will show up if I try to draw a pentagon p=5 all of the lines show up.
On a different forum someone suggested adding 0.5f to the coordinates of all vertices to change how openGl rounds. I tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're actually trying to draw? The first loop looks like you're calculating points on a circle. I don't see definitions for `p`, `q` and `TAU`. In any case, you're then drawing lines between alternating points. When you say that you get two lines for 4 vertices, that's exactly what you coded. For a vertex count of 4, you generate a line between points 0 and 1, and a line between points 2 and 3. For odd numbers, maybe you wrap around the circle more than once? Then the second turn would draw different lines if the count is odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Always provide a screenshot of what you are seeing and a Paint drawing of what you want to achieve*

Change

```
sf::VertexArray lines = sf::VertexArray(sf::Lines, vertices.getVertexCount());
for(int iii = 0; iii < lines.getVertexCount()-1; iii+=2) {
    lines[iii] = vertices[iii];
    lines[iii+1] = vertices[iii+1];
    lines[iii].color = sf::Color(255,(iii)*50,255,255);//sf::Color::White;
    lines[iii+1].color = sf::Color(255,(iii+1)*50,255,255);//sf::Color::White;
}
```

to

```
sf::VertexArray lines = sf::VertexArray(sf::LinesStrip, vertices.getVertexCount());
for(int iii = 0; iii < lines.getVertexCount(); iii+=1) {
    lines[iii] = vertices[iii];
    lines[iii].color = sf::Color(255,(iii)*50,255,255);//sf::Color::White;
}
```

As the primitive type sf::Lines require 2x points than lines you draw. **sf::LinesStrip** should do the trick in VertexArray.

Comment: Sorry that didn't change anything (at least in the display.) Here is a screenshot of what it does: http://s17.postimg.org/bv592i3rj/example.png

Comment: Could you expand the sample on what `p`, `q` and `TAU` are? Therein might the flaw lay.